# How do I save a picture gallery in DataBase?

Tags: java, android, database

I need to save picture gallery and save it in database,
I have the address of the image device.

My question is how I keep it in a database?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Once you have tried to do this, post any specific issues for better assistance.

Answer (score 0):

i need to add the image to parse.. 
I have comment on: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(targetImage);
this is the name changed = targetImage - This image has chosen to basically gallery (name changed).
thank you bro

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            // Locate the image in res > drawable-hdpi
                    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(targetImage);
```